# How to add a line feed in html without using <br> or other tags

Tags: html, web, escaping, xss

When processing a html form, I need to append some text to a text field before saving it to database. To make it prettier, I need to add a line feed in between:

```
userText = userText + "<br>" + appendedText;
# save userText in database
```

The problem is,when fetching the text to render web page, for protection agains XSS, I need to escape text from database before rendering. Thus, `<br>` in userText is rendered as `<br>` instead of a line feed.

So I am wondering if there is any other way to produce a line feed other than `<br>`?

I have tried "\n" "\r\n", and "
", none of them work.

Also, the appended text is in the same element with original text, so css with 'display:block' is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `\n` and then after fetching the data from the database and prior to outputting it, replace all the `\n` with `<br />`. 
This way you are still safe for `XSS`, and you have full control over the output.

Comment: Sometimes elegance is overrated :)

Comment: I just found a Django template filter that is exactly your solution: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javaScript to get the form values you can easily use `"\n"` to add a new line to the value you want to save;

```
var toSave = FormValue + "\n\n" + "extratext";
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/manishkumarshr/djBH7/)